# Opencv DNN module was not built with CUDA backend, however it was built

Tags: opencv, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have build opencv with cuda support. However when i run the opencv function that uses cuda backend i get following error.
[image: Opencv CUDA Error on Jetson nano]

I am running my application on Jetson Nano 4Gb developer board. Here are the stats from my board

[image: Jetson Board information]

OpenCV build info

```
--     Disabled:                    python3
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv hdf java js julia matlab ovis sfm ts viz
--     Applications:                apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         YES
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.22.30)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.56.4)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build Jasper (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_2)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
--       avresample:                YES (3.7.0)
--     GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.4)
--     Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.2, CUFFT CUBLAS)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             53
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
-- 
--   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.2.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/fft/opencv/workspace/opencv-4.4.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.17)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.17)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
--     install path:                lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/python-2.7
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
```

Script used :

1. sudo apt-get purge *libopencv*
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
4. sudo apt-get install -y libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
5. sudo apt-get install -y libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libdc1394-22-dev
6. sudo apt-get install -y libv4l-dev v4l-utils qv4l2 v4l2ucp
7. sudo apt-get install -y curl
8. mkdir workspace
9. cd workspace
10. curl -L https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.4.0.zip -o opencv-4.4.0.zip
11. curl -L https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.4.0.zip -o opencv_contrib-4.4.0.zip
12. unzip opencv-4.4.0.zip
13. unzip opencv_contrib-4.4.0.zip
14. cd opencv-4.4.0/
15. mkdir release
16. cd release/
17. cmake -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D WITH_CUDNN=ON -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN="5.3,6.2,7.2" -D CUDA_ARCH_PTX="" -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-${version}/modules -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
18. make
19. sudo make install

Comment: Did you clean/remove any old opencv versions before building the new one?

Comment: Yes i did sudo purge *libopencv

Comment: it removes opencv safely ? Please share the warning and console output as text instead of their pic

Comment: Can you use and print cv getBuildInformation in your program?

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of errors and builds, they can’t be searched for by others

Comment: This is the script i have used to build opencv